# Add column index to dataframe based on another column (user in this case)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a dataframe as given below where the last column represents the number of times the user has searched for the location and stay

```
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb7|                     1|
|Sanders|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|                     1|
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|                     3|
|  Hanks|             Tokyo|      airbnb8|                     2|
|  Larry|             Hanoi|             |                     2|
|  Mango|             Seoul|      airbnb5|                     1|
|  Larry|             Hanoi|      airbnb1|                     2|
```

which i want to transform as follows

```
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb7|                     1|    1|
|Sanders|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|                     1|    1|
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|                     3|    2|
|  Hanks|             Tokyo|      airbnb8|                     2|    3|
|  Larry|             Hanoi|             |                     2|    0|
|  Mango|             Seoul|      airbnb5|                     1|    1|
|  Larry|             Hanoi|      airbnb1|                     2|    1|
```

Notice that column 5 represents the index of the unique combination of options(location+stay) that user selected. 
  eg

```
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb7|                     1|    1|
|  Hanks|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|                     3|    2|
|  Hanks|             Tokyo|      airbnb8|                     2|    3|
```

I tried using groupBy/Agg to do this by implementing a udf function as the following in the agg function.

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("User", "clickedDestination", "clickedAirbnb")
                      .agg(indexUserDetailsUDF(col("clickedAirbnb")) as ("clickedAirbnbIndex"))
```

And the udf as follows

```
var cnt = 0
val airbnbClickIndex:(String) => String = (airbnb) => {
  if(airbnb== "") "null" //return 0 for airbnbClickIndex when airbnb is empty
  else{cnt+=1; cnt.toString()} //otherwise return incremented value
}
val indexUserDetailsUDF = udf(airbnbClickIndex)
```

But this is not working. Any input is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Update1: Daniel's suggestion of dense_rank does the following to a user

```
|Meera|         Amsterdam|     airbnb12|         1|     1|
|Meera|         Amsterdam|      airbnb2|         1|     2|
|Meera|         Amsterdam|      airbnb7|         1|     3|
|Meera|         Amsterdam|      airbnb8|         1|     4|
|Meera|         Bangalore|             |         1|     5|
|Meera|         Bangalore|     airbnb11|         1|     6|
|Meera|         Bangalore|      airbnb8|         1|     7|
|Meera|             Hanoi|      airbnb1|         2|     8|
|Meera|             Hanoi|      airbnb2|         1|     9|
|Meera|             Hanoi|      airbnb7|         1|    10|
|Meera|            Mumbai|             |         1|    11|
|Meera|              Oslo|             |         2|    12|
|Meera|              Oslo|      airbnb8|         1|    13|
|Meera|             Paris|             |         1|    14|
|Meera|             Paris|     airbnb11|         1|    15|
|Meera|             Paris|      airbnb6|         1|    16|
|Meera|             Paris|      airbnb7|         1|    17|
|Meera|             Paris|      airbnb8|         2|    18|
|Meera|         Rotterdam|      airbnb2|         1|    19|
```

I assumed dense_rank will push those records with empty field values (in this case 3rd empty field) to the last. Is this correct?

Comment: What is your expected result for records with empty values in the third column? With my proposed solution, they will be considered as normal text, so each empty string for each (user, clickedDestination) pair will be given a different index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you probably want a windowed rank. You could try the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy("User").orderBy("User", "clickedDestination", "clickedAirbnb")

val result = df.withColumn("clickedAirbnbIndex", dense_rank().over(window))
```

If needed, you can find some good reading about window functions in Spark [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

Also, the [functions package api documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) is very useful.